# Query to run max and min

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am trying to run a query but I'm having some problems with it because I'm using a `nvarchar` column to get a percentage column which gives me the percentage from the database of different data that I have. That column is called "Filetype" and what I have there is all the Extension's that I put there f.e: .exe, .zip, etc.

Then I thought I could get in the same query the `MAX` and `MIN` of percentage the problem is it is not so easy with that data type values. I've made a query in Microsoft Visual Studio

```
SELECT 
Filetype AS [Extensão], 
COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros],
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percentagem (%)],
SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)],
NULL AS [Convertido para MB],
MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],
MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM infofile  
GROUP BY Filetype
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
COUNT('Nº de extensões'),
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
SUM(Filesize),
SUM(Filesize) / 1024,
NULL,
NULL
FROM infofile
```

But If I use this query it will fill all the rows and what I want it to do is the same from the lines after `UNION ALL`. I will show you the output by now[image]

And I want to display that `MAX` and `MIN` as I will show you with arrows.
[image]

That row is where I display all the final results. And I want change it there by adding `MAX` and `MIN` values

Your query result
[image]

Comment: Expressions `MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)]` and 
`MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]` both give aggregate over all the table and may be safely used instead of NULLs in the last part  where you need all table aggregates. I'd rather asked why you need them at first part?

Comment: I need them after UNION ALL if possible. Or create a single query which just gives me the max and min

Comment: Are you saying that you need something different in the first part? What should be correct `[Min. Percentagem (%)]` for `.bat` or `.txt` then, for example?

Comment: Imagine I have 7 .exe, 5 .zip and from there I have a percentage from everything. And then I would like to know what is the max and the min percentage value .

Comment: Ok, then min/max percentage is not relevant to the first part at all. Why not to drop  (or set to NULL) them in first part? And simply Select min[Percentagem (%)], max[Percentagem (%)] at the second?

Comment: I've done it. But if you look and the last printscreen of my output that I've posted here it will shows me 100.000000 instead of MIN and MAX that I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
with cte as
(
SELECT 
Filetype AS [Extensão], 
COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros],
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percentagem (%)],
SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)],
NULL AS [Convertido para MB],
MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],
MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM infofile  
GROUP BY Filetype
)
select [Extensão],[Nº de ficheiros],[Percentagem (%)],[Total(KB)],[Convertido para MB],NULL AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],NULL AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]   from cte
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
COUNT('Nº de extensões'),
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
SUM(Filesize),
SUM(Filesize) / 1024,
(Select MAX([Min. Percentagem (%)]) from cte) as [Min. Percentagem (%)] ,
(Select MAX([Max. Percentagem (%)] from cte as [Max. Percentagem (%)])
FROM infofile
```

I have done nothing but put your 1st query in a cte and used it to return your min amd max % for the query after UNION ALL as well. I hope this is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it gives me this message cte.Max. Percentagem (%)" could not be bound.

Comment: Oh yes, you need to join cte in the query after UNION ALL. I have joined it now with condition simply 1 = 1, as I thought you don't really need to join it on any column. Please check now. I cannot run your query as I don't have your schema and data required.

Comment: I have cleaned it a little more. Please check.

Comment: Not bad. But I still get all rows filled before UNION ALL

Comment: Ok. Is that what I really want

Comment: My friend , somewhere in your question it is creating confusion whether you need those values in all rows or not. That's where in fact everyone is getting confused. Please check edited version.

Comment: I think I've got it. I've solved the problem I think. I will run some tests with my application and then I will feed you ok?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine. Can you give me some overview/explanation of what you've done by doing your query?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I have taken first part of your query and put it in a CTE , which allow me to use the record set returned by this query further in my next query. Then I selected all columns from cte , except last two, which you needed NULL, hence selected simply NULL. Next step is UNION ALL, here I have re-used recordset we have in cte to get max of [Min. Percentagem (%)] and max of [Max. Percentagem (%)] . You can get the basic of CTE clear from https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/ I like this article.

Comment: Ok man!! That was helpful. I've learned a lot today with it thank you. Another question, if I wanna add Decimal(10,2) in MAX and MIN I have to add CAST?

Comment: Happy to know that it helped :) and yea sure, go ahead using CAST.

Comment: Good question. Looks like you need to convert only to show data on your application in little meaningful way. If you add it in your first query, SQL engine has to perform the datatype conversion operation on every row, while you don't really need it. You can simply add CAST in UNION ALL query, that too outside MAX function, so that once MAX function is run on every row, and your maximum value is fetched, SQL engine simply applies CAST function on 1 value only. So, concluding, it would be better to add CAST function outside MAX function in UNION ALL query.

Comment: I already solved my problem in one of them doing this: CAST(((SELECT MAX([Min. Percentagem (%)]) FROM fileinfo)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)] but I am having some problems with the other expression CAST((SELECT MAX([Max. Percentagem (%)]) FROM fileinfo) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Max. Percentagem (%)])

Comment: Solved ')' ahahah Thank you a lot man for your help. Have a very good day

Comment: Almost forgot about it. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

You could replicate your logic in a cross join to the data in the second query, something like this;

```
SELECT Filetype AS [Extensão]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros]
    ,CAST((
            (COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM infofile
                )
            ) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS [Percentagem (%)]
    ,SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)]
    ,NULL AS [Convertido para MB]
    ,MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)]
    ,MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM infofile
GROUP BY Filetype

UNION ALL
(
SELECT '---------------'
    ,COUNT('Nº de extensões')
    ,(
        (COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (
            SELECT COUNT(Filetype)
            FROM infofile
            )
        )
    ,SUM(Filesize)
    ,SUM(Filesize) / 1024
    ,a.[Min. Percentagem (%)]
    ,a.[Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM infofile i
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
MAX(a.[Min. Percentagem (%)]) [Min. Percentagem (%)]
,MAX(a.[Max. Percentagem (%)]) [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM
(SELECT Filetype AS [Extensão]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros]
    ,CAST((
            (COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM infofile
                )
            ) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS [Percentagem (%)]
    ,SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)]
    ,NULL AS [Convertido para MB]
    ,MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)]
    ,MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM infofile
GROUP BY Filetype) ft
) a
)
```

Comment: I know that. But if I put that 2 lines(MIN and MAX) after UNION ALL it will give me 100.00 and not the results that I want. I've just updated my post. This is what happen after running your query.

Comment: I've just run it and gave me some erros 'The multi-part identifier "ft.Max. Percentagem (%)" could not be bound'

Comment: yeah, change that to a. rather than ft. i've just updated that too

Comment: It keep giving me messages in this lines. (SELECT DISTINCT
a.[Min. Percentagem (%)]
,a.[Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM

Comment: I'm having troubles because I don't have data to look at, sorry about that. Try adding an 'a' at the end of the code, i'll edit now.

Comment: In the last line it gives me a message because of that 'a' that you've just added "Incorrect syntax near 'a'"

Comment: ok, try pasting all of the code (i've just made an edit) into your SSMS and let me know the exact error message (if you get one)

Comment: It keeps giving me that messages after CROSS JOIN where you got "(SELECT 
MAX(a.[Min. Percentagem (%)]) [Min. Percentagem (%)]
,MAX(a.[Max. Percentagem (%)]) [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM" you see that?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a real column on my table called "Percentage" and there I could get the values and after it making a column for each MAX and MIN. Do you think that it will make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you need to add an aggregated row to your select statement, where you can derive the min and max of the aggregated rows. Here is what you can do using a #temp table. Further you can drop the #temp table once not needed.

```
SELECT 
Filetype AS [Extensão], 
COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros],
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percentagem (%)],
SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)],
SUM(Filesize) / 1024 AS [Convertido para MB],
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
INTO #temp
FROM infofile  
GROUP BY Filetype;

SELECT *
FROM #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
SUM([Nº de ficheiros]),
SUM([Percentagem (%)]), 
SUM([Total(KB)]),
SUM([Total(KB)]) / 1024,
MIN([Min. Percentagem (%)]),
MAX([Max. Percentagem (%)])
FROM #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Let me know if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Your query made the same thing that mine did. Fill all the rows with MIN and MAX values.

Comment: Can you explain functionally what exactly is it you need in the min/max Column for the total row and for initial rows?

Comment: I need MAX and MIN because I will use this query in a DGV which gives the user a complete overview for what user made you know? That info is useful for them

Comment: No no.. My question is: what exactly fills Min/Max in the columns? Can you make a small excel and put up the desired output in your question?

Comment: I tried to understand your question, which definitely took me a lot of time... and edited my answer. See if this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Probably no need for min/max percentage at first part, just at the second. As far as I've got it from comments, look at

```
WITH totals_by_ext AS (
  SELECT 
    Filetype AS [Extensão], 
    COUNT(*) AS [Nº de ficheiros],
    CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percentagem (%)],
    SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)],
    CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Convertido para MB],
    CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],
    CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
  FROM infofile  
  GROUP BY Filetype
)
SELECT * 
FROM totals_by_ext
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  '---------------',
  COUNT([Extensão]),
  SUM([Nº de extensões]) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)),
  SUM([Total(KB)]),
  SUM([Total(KB)]) / 1024,
  MIN([Percentagem (%)]) AS [Min. Percentagem (%)],
  MAX([Percentagem (%)]) AS [Max. Percentagem (%)]
FROM totals_by_ext;
```